# making this nested for loop more pythonic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a clunky (but working) piece of code as shown:

```
plus_cords = []
for i in range(len(pluses)):
    plus_cords.append([ [pluses[i][0], pluses[i][1]] ])
    for j in range(1, pluses[i][2] + 1):
        plus_cords[i].append([pluses[i][0] - j, pluses[i][1]])
        plus_cords[i].append([pluses[i][0] + j, pluses[i][1]])
        plus_cords[i].append([pluses[i][0], pluses[i][1] - j])
        plus_cords[i].append([pluses[i][0], pluses[i][1] + j])
```

where 'pluses' is a list of a list of 3 integers.

```
pluses = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 4, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 4, 1], [2, 5, 0], [3, 0, 0], [3, 1, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 1, 0], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 0]]
```

I'm looking for ideas on how this can be made more readable and efficient, basically more "pythonic".

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Noted, I'll keep this in mind. I have also posted it over there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer by Samwise, but broken down into separate steps, and actually producing the same result as your original code:

First, of course, we can iterate the elements of `pluses` directly, instead of using an index, and unpack them to their three constituting values, already making the code a good deal more readable:

```
plus_cords = []
for p0, p1, p2 in pluses:
    cords = [ [p0, p1] ]
    for j in range(1, p2 + 1):
        cords.append([p0 - j, p1])
        cords.append([p0 + j, p1])
        cords.append([p0, p1 - j])
        cords.append([p0, p1 + j])
    plus_cords.append(cords)
```

Then, we can try to turn the inner loop into a list comprehension. This is a bit tricky, as we have to use a nested generator and unpack that into the list comprehension to differentiate between the single first element and the rest:

```
plus_cords = []
for p0, p1, p2 in pluses:
    cords = [[p0, p1], *(x for j in range(1, p2 + 1)
                           for x in ([p0 - j, p1], [p0 + j, p1], [p0, p1 - j], [p0, p1 + j]))]
    plus_cords.append(cords)
```

Once we have that, we can make the outer loop a list comprehension, too.

```
plus_cords = [[[p0, p1], *(x for j in range(1, p2 + 1)
                             for x in ([p0 - j, p1], [p0 + j, p1], [p0, p1 - j], [p0, p1 + j]))]
              for p0, p1, p2 in pluses]
```

Alternatively, instead of the second step, you could settle for a `set` of `tuples` (to prevent duplicates) and get the `[p0, p1]` case with starting with `j=0`.

```
plus_cords = [{x for j in range(p2 + 1)
                 for x in ((p0 - j, p1), (p0 + j, p1), (p0, p1 - j), (p0, p1 + j))}
              for p0, p1, p2 in pluses]
```

Comment: Thank you Tobias. For the outer for loop in the first step, what would be the difference between "for p0, p1, p2 in pluses" and "for [p0, p1, p2] in pluses". I get the correct result either way. For step 2 onwards, I'll definitely have to do some reading to understand. Would you have any resources for this particular content?

Comment: @Muffi (1) There is not really a difference. (2) Best just try those in an interactive python shell: simple list literal `[1, 2, 3]`; unpacking another iterable into a list literal `[1, *(2, 3)]`; list comp. `[x*2 for x in range(3)]`; list comp with 2 loops: `[x+y for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]`, then try to combine those in different ways. What you see in step 2 is a generator expression with 2 for-loops that is unpacked into a list literal.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's preferable to iterate over the elements of a list rather than iterating over it by index, and to build a new list via comprehension rather than iteratively `append`ing.

```
plus_cords = [[
    [p0, p1], [p0 - j, p1], [p0 + j, p1], [p0, p1 - j], [p0, p1 + j]
] for [p0, p1, p2] in pluses for j in range(1, p2 + 1)]
```

Not positive I got it right since I don't have sample data for `pluses` to test with, but that should be in the general ballpark.

Comment: This has a syntax error. It looks like the `for j` part is in the wrong place

Comment: Yes, I did try this on my end, but i'm getting a syntax error. Although this does look much more readable, thanks. I'll try to debug the syntax error and post over here.

Comment: ah yes, we're doing one list per element of `pluses`, which means we want `for p... in pluses for j in range(...)`.  Updated.

Comment: That does get rid of the syntax error, but doesn't lead to the expected output. I'll add an example of pluses to the main question for your reference